# GCC illegal instruction

Tags: c++, gcc

When I compile this code:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 mt(dev());
    std::cout << mt() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And then try to run the resulting executable with `gdb` I get this error:

> Program received signal `SIGILL`, Illegal instruction. `std::(anonymous namespace)::__x86_rdrand ()` at
>   /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/random.cc:69 69
>   /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/random.cc: No such file or directory.

I use *arch linux* with a *Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T8100*.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you perchance compile the code for a newer CPU than what you have so GCC used some instructions your CPU does not have?

Comment: Inspect the stack , easiest way to get this (illigal instruction) is to trample on a return address by running off an array or similar (any UB).  Return then goes to an address that does not contain a valid instruction.

Comment: added sample code

Comment: @Zeldhoron that doesn't crash for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vXUD7pgnoAptd2Pt  Running that exact code crashes on your computer?

Comment: @xaxxon i literally have no idea what is happening here so, yeah

Comment: Please supply the *exact* compiler commandline you used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is "Illegal instruction", and the only hint you get is `__x86_rdrand()`. Googling rdrand leads to the [RDRAND instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand), which appears to have been added for Ivy Bridge Processors, which your Core 2 Duo most certainly is not.  (It's a Penryn on this chart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Intel_processor_roadmap)

OK, so your CPU doesn't have RDRAND.  That means the compiler must have the wrong information about what it's target is.  With GCC, the flag to adjust is `-march`.  In your case, `-march=core2` should do it.  It should also be ok to say `-march=native`, which will target exactly what you're compiling on.